# stormpath - how to control the directory used

Tags: python, flask, stormpath

using the `Flask-Stormpath` pip. here is the setup

```
app.config['STORMPATH_APPLICATION'] = my_app_name
```

I don't see any `STORMPATH_DIRECTORY` settings in the [docs](https://flask-stormpath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#initialize-flask-stormpath) to allow developers to use applicationA with multiple directories.

EDIT:
for login, i've extracted the `authenticate_password` method
and I can pass the specific director like randall has stated

```
 authenticate_password(username, password, account_store=self.directory)
```

for the user sign up , I can't seem to find a solution

This is how i'm signing up in one of my applications:

authenticate_password(username, password, account_store=self.directory)

```
from flask.ext.stormpath import User as StormpathUser
data = {
            'email':  self._api_user_name_to_email(username),
            'password': password,
            'given_name': username,
            'surname': username,

        }
StormpathUser.create(**data)
```

any idea as how to explictly sign up the user in a spcific directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported (a preferred directory). In the integration, your first priority directory is used by default to create new users, etc.

If this will not work for your use case, you can drop down to using the `stormpath_manager.application` object to create users manually in whatever directory you want.

EG:

`stormpath_manager.application.create_account({...}, account_store=some_other_directory)`

Comment: thanks. can you explain as to how this would work with google login (social user) using the same app for both localhost and staging . getting `redirect_uri_mismatch` since I can't change the authorized redirect uri programmatically .

Comment: I can't map 2 google directories to one application getting `A GOOGLE Directory is already assigned to this Application. An Application may be assigned only one GOOGLE Directory.`

Comment: maybe there is a way to support multiple authorized redirect uris per one directory

Comment: What you'll want to do is create a separate Stormpath tenant for each of your environments: staging, production, etc. This is how we recommend you do it -- this way you can have completely separate admins, keys, and resources that are not at all shared on the same tenant -- and hopefully reduces any errors where bad things happen to production data on accident.